# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run my query but return 
error : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

```
    Select 
    u.*,
    (
        Select 
            COUNT(cDays) as c,
            SUM(un) as un,
            SUM(vcs) as vcs
        From
        (
            Select
                s.DateSales as cDays,
                SUM(s.Un) as Un,
                SUM(s.VCS) as vcs
            From
                dbSales.dbo.Sales s
            Where
                s.IDX = u.IDX And s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)
            Group by
                s.DateSales
        ) as sct
    )

From 
    unikat u
)
```

Comment: Add another tag with SQL tag to specify your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `APPLY` operator for the subquery:

```
Select 
    u.*,
    sct.*
From 
    unikat u
    OUTER APPLY 
    (
        Select
            COUNT(DISTINCT(s.DateSales)) as cDays,
            SUM(s.Un) as Un,
            SUM(s.VCS) as vcs
        From
            dbSales.dbo.Sales s
        Where
            s.IDX = u.IDX And 
            s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)
    ) AS sct
```

You can incorporate any amount of columns resulting from the `APPLY` operator. Use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `OUTER APPLY` if you want to filter `NULL` matching results.

Comment: clause with will not work because you didnt add table 'u'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select *
  From unikat u, (
    Select 
        COUNT(cDays) as c,
        SUM(un) as un,
        SUM(vcs) as vcs
    From
    (
        Select
            s.DateSales as cDays,
            SUM(s.Un) as Un,
            SUM(s.VCS) as vcs
        From
            dbSales.dbo.Sales s
        Where
            s.IDX = u.IDX And s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) 
            And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)
        Group by
            s.DateSales
    ) 
) a
```

Comment: And this query working properly ?                                                               
           Select 
            COUNT(cDays) as c,
            SUM(un) as un,
            SUM(vcs) as vcs
        From
        (
            Select
                s.DateSales as cDays,
                SUM(s.Un) as Un,
                SUM(s.VCS) as vcs
            From
                dbSales.dbo.Sales s
            Where
                s.IDX = u.IDX And s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)
            Group by
                s.DateSales )

Comment: yeap, it's working ok. but in subquery is problem because im trying to return 3 variables in main query.

Comment: Try now. Edited answer. Maybe join tables.

Answer (score 0):

add `select top 1`

```
  Select 
    u.*,
    (
        Select top 1
            COUNT(cDays) as c,
            SUM(un) as un,
            SUM(vcs) as vcs
        From
        (
            Select
                s.DateSales as cDays,
                SUM(s.Un) as Un,
                SUM(s.VCS) as vcs
            From
                dbSales.dbo.Sales s
            Where
                s.IDX = u.IDX And s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)
            Group by
                s.DateSales
        ) as sct
    )

From 
    unikat u
)
```

Comment: is not working too because i trying to return 3 variables in subquery

Comment: what's the relationship between your unikat table to your subquery?

Comment: s.IDX = u.IDX And s.DateSales Between DATEADD(dd,-8, u.DateS) And DATEADD(dd,-1, u.DateS)

Comment: seems your joining the sum() to your unikat table, please add expected output